# How to do Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel table, about 100 rows and 170 columns.

If I use the whole area markup and adjust the width of the content columns (using the double arrow between the column header markup), it takes Excel about 3 seconds (to auto-adjust all columns).

When I do it with the VBA code through `Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit` function, the whole operation (auto-adjust all columns) takes a few minutes!
How do I this action faster?

In addition, I subsequently hide some columns using `Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`, but the time difference is not that important there.

I'm not using `Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True` inside a loop.

Complete VBA code. When making it manually, I selected the square on left top (on crossing of rows and columns names) and then double-clicked double-arrow.

```vb
Sub Hromadne()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
    RadekDatSkryti = Sheets("Hromadné").Range("C3").Value
    Rows(RadekDatSkryti).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    For i = 3 To 167
        If Cells(RadekDatSkryti, i).Value = 0 Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            'Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you keep the Q & A free of text that distracts from the question this will be a more useful resource for you and other users. You could start here [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to use the site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try manual calculation mode. Speeds up my macro x10

```vb
Sub Hromadne()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
'turn off automatic calculation'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
'Manual Calculate if formulas need to updated when automatic calculation is off
' - insert where needed
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hromadné").Calculate

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
RadekDatSkryti = Sheets("Hromadné").Range("C3").Value
Rows(RadekDatSkryti).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
For i = 3 To 167
    If Cells(RadekDatSkryti, i).Value = 0 Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        'Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next i
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'turn on automactic calculation'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to use 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual , but the time difference is only few seconds. It seems the problem is not in re-counting data, but maybe in using of "working memory"? The file I'm working with is not intended to saving changes - so I upload data into it and then I work with them with macros. It seems more operations I did, the slower it is. But it is strange, that slowing is only in macros - when I did Auto-Adjust manually, it is still quick. Any ideas why the same operations in macro is much slower than when doing it manually?